# statusBar for iOS7 in Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I want to resolve issue with `statusBar` in iOS7. I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7) and this solution works great in Xcode 5. But when I tried this code in Xcode 4.6.3 I got 2 errors:

1. `No visible @interface for 'MyController' declares the selector
   'setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate'`;
2. `Use of undeclared identifier
   'UIStatusBarStyleLightContent'`.

The first problem was solved by using this code: `[self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];` but I can't resolve the second  error.

Comment: If you build against SDK6 and run on iOS7 you shouldn't have to do anything, so you could use respondsToSelector to see if setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate exists. Only if you build against SDK7 and run on iOS7, the status bar behavior will change.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin Wasn't me, but possibly because iOS 7 is still covered by an NDA.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of NDA police around with nothing better to do than slap your wrists... !! , however you haven't disclosed anything that can't be found out by anyone with little effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are iOS 7 features that won't compile in XCode 4.6.3 which is trying to compile against iOS 6. You need to conditionally compile them out.

Wrap the offending code with:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
    //iOS 7 only stuff here
#endif
```