# Add write a review rate us feature to my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, irate

I want to add some sort of a "Write a Review" or "Rate Us" feature to my app so my customers can easily rate and review my iOS app.

My app is already on the store,

I was wondering how to do this. I want the alert to be displayed after say the app has launched 10 times if that would be possible. And how can I create an maybe later alternative which displays the alert maybe 15 launches of the app later?

After searching i found iRate example, i have imported `#import "iRate.h"` in my `appdelegate`

and i have wrote this in `appdelegate`,

```
+(void)initialize{
    [iRate sharedInstance].previewMode=YES;

}
```

When i launch my app alert displays but it shows warnings in the log:

- iRate is checking http://itunes.apple.com/US/lookup?bundleId=com.AppName to retrieve the App Store details...
- iRate could not find the App Store ID for this application. If the application is not intended for App Store release then you must specify a custom ratingsURL.
- iRate could not find your app on iTunes. If your app is not yet on the store or is not intended for App Store release then don't worry about this
- iRate could not find the App Store ID for this application. If the application is not intended for App Store release then you must specify a custom ratingsURL.

How to remove this warnings and how to link my app with iTunes rating page of my app ?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doing this type of rating i m used [Apprirater](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/appirater) for iOS  take a Look this is very simple and easy to config and manage. From the [GithubLink read Getting Started](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater#getting-started)

and `configure` it

```
[Appirater setAppId:@"552035781"];//here you need to put your App id
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:1];
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:10];
[Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1];
[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2];
[Appirater setDebug:YES]; // set NO while you upload App into appstore this YES for testing
```

that Appear alert as par you configration like Bellow screenshot:-

[image]

**UPDATE**

adding This Three class in to your Project:-

[image]

> Add the CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, and StoreKit frameworks to your project. Be sure to change Required to Optional for StoreKit in your target's Build Phases » Link Binary with Libraries section.

Comment: It shows ERROR: `us of undeclared identifier UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` in `appiarater.m` file

Comment: witch ios sdk are you ussing ?

Comment: i use same configiration and working fine check my update answer have you add this three file

Comment: take a look this issue with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375832/statusbar-for-ios7-in-xcode-4-6

Comment: I changed my `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` to `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` it removes error but when i run my app it doesn't ask for Review.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37230/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-krunal)

Comment: i used this for cocos2d-x in appcontroller.mm file.. am not able to get any alert...  [Appirater setAppId:@"7405885"];
    [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:1];
    [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:1];
    [Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1];
    [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2];
    [Appirater setDebug:YES];