# statusbar overlapping content in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

With iOS7 the toolbar I placed right under the statusbar has merged with the statusbar

[image]

but when I move the toolbar 20px down, then it looks like

[image]

How can I have the effect of the first picture (statusbar with same color as toolbar) but not merging it with the statusbar. Or should this be done differently in iOS7?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set yourself as the toolbar delegate. Then in your view controller, implement `UIBarPositioningDelegate`. Implement it as follows:

**Objective-C**

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
  return .TopAttached
}
```

Also make sure you move your toolbar 20 points down (as you already did), or right underneath the status bar, for this effect to take place.

Comment: This will result as a crash on ios10

Answer (score 0):

Try set in plist "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO