# UIBarButtonItem move down ios 7

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem

[image: Back UIBarButtonItem with navigation bar title]

code 1 :

```
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                             target:self action:@selector(exits)];
    //[item setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:10.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:+5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

code 2:

```
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                             target:self action:@selector(exits)];
    //[item setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:10.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 50) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I tried both the above code this did not work

What i want to do is get back UIBarButtonItem move down in level of My Example title.
How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem isn't with your `UIBarButtonItem`, but with the placement of your entire `UINavigationBar`. Your `UINavigationBar` should be moved down by 20 pixels to account for the Status Bar. Make the changes written in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896966/statusbar-overlapping-content-in-ios7) and everything should line up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move the text down you can use…

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] 
       setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 6) 
                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for late answer. If you are still looking for answer, try the following. It worked for me:

```
item.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
item.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: XCode 5.1.1 doesn't appear to accept this. Are there any library imports needed to access 'contentVerticalAlignment' and 'contentEdgeInsets' ?