# When hiding the statusbar my navigation bar moves up in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I am trying to hide the statusbar but maintain the "bigger" navigationbar height. Right now when I hide the statusbar by setting `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` to `YES` and then calling `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`. The problem with this is that the navigationbar will slide up and won't leave space for the notification I'm trying to show. Simply adding a view over the statusbar is not an option, our statusbar/navigation has the fancy blur effect. Does anyone have a clue how to maintain the standard navigationbar height with the status bar height and remove the statusbar from that?

Edit; what I ended up doing is taking a risk and getting the UIWindow of the statusbar via a private API and offsetting that.

Edit 2; App got approved with the private API. Be cautious though!

Comment: A `UINavigationBar` is a `UIView` subclass.  Set its frame to whatever you want.  If you're using a `UINavigationController` which is setting its frame, subclass that and override `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Full investigation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929220/show-hide-uitoolbar-match-finger-movement-precisely-as-in-for-example-ios7-s

Comment: check this reference link [customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

Comment: Some screenshots to understand what, and more important why you want to do this could help.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom UIView with its frame as

```
customView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Also hide your status bar by following the below steps

**Go to info.plist and add two attributes if not present. set "Status bar is initially hidden" to `YES` and set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO`. This will hide status bar for your app.**

Comment: customView height should be `self.view.frame.size.height - 20` :)

Comment: The bounty was automatically awarded, but the answer is mostly correct. I solved my problem by making a replacement `UINavigationView` class that I manually add to my views, while the real navigation bar of my controllers stays hidden. Although I DO use a view-controller based status bar appearance plist item and override `prefersStatusBarHidden`

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your view Controller:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, because I don't want to lose extended layout.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this once. I ended up creating a custom navigationBar of my own and then just set the frame as:

```
navBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

It worked for me at the time. Just try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use of [`positionForBar:` method of `UIBarPositioningDelegate Protocol.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarPositioningDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIBarPositioningDelegate/positionForBar%3a)

I don't want to put another answer or copy/past so you should take closer look at following question\answers. :)

[iOS 7 Status Bar Collides With NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar)
[iOS 7 UIToolBar Overriding With Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935821/ios-7-uitoolbar-overriding-with-status-bar)
[statusbar overlapping content in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896966/statusbar-overlapping-content-in-ios7)

Comment: hello, i am working with TLYShyNavBar and carbonkit for navigationbar hide like youtube home page you have idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround here: subclass `UINavigationController` override method:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if (self.navigationBar.frameMinY < 1) {
        self.navigationBar.frameHeight = 64;
    } else {
        self.navigationBar.frameHeight = 44;
    }
}
```

in which set `frameMinY` is set `frame.origin.y` and set `frameHeight` is set `frame.size.height`

Comment: This method is broken on ios11