# Fake Status Bar Color when Navigation Bar is hidden

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm running into an issue with status bars & navigation bars. By default the navigation bar of `UINavigationController` extends behind the status bar and colors it (left screenshot).

When the search bar is used, I hide the navigation bar. This results in an uncolored Status Bar. Apple's Mail app does not have this issue.

Is there any other solution than creating a separate UIView with a background color and placing it behind the status bar?

[image: Image that shows hidden and not-hidden navigation bar, and how this affects the status bar color]

Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: research `UIBarPositioningDelegate`

Comment: Thanks to @Desdenova suggestion, I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/18897105/3512120, which solved my problem, and likely yours aswell.

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the navigationBar why don't you also update the appearance of your UIStatusBar.

Implement this function in your NavigationController:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    //Have an if statement to determine which UIStatusBarStyle to return, i.e if the navigationBar is hidden 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
 }
```

And call it when you hide your navigation bar by using this:

```
 [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Another option is to do the follow:

Set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO in your info pList file.
Then you can call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your IB (or programatically), try to check the simulated metrics for the top bar: you should set it from opaque to translucent (navigation bar).

*Note*: By default, the navigation bar is translucent. You should get the "colored"** status bar for *free*.

** as defined by `UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor`