# Status Bar White Opaque on Launch

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uistatusbar

My initial view controller is a navigation controller and its root view controller is a `UIViewController` which conforms to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol. The content for my pages are three unique view controllers which have both a scene in the storyboard and a swift file.

I am hiding the navigation bar in the root view controller's `viewDidLoad()`.

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

When the app launches, the status bar is white and opaque. As soon as I scroll to the next page, it becomes translucent and the background color of the page shows through.

**Appearance on Launch**

[image]

**Appearance While Swiping to Next Page**

[image]

Can someone please help me understand what is happening here and how to fix it? In case it is not obvious, I want the second behavior from launch; the status bar is translucent and the page background shows through.

I have tried

- In `viewDidLoad()`:         `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent`
- In the root view controller:

  ```
  override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
      return .Default
  }
  ```

  Followed by `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in `viewDidLoad()`
- In the root view controller:

  ```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(true)
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  }
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad()` (above `navigationBar.hidden`):

  ```
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  ```

As a note, when I remove the navigation controller and just make the root view controller the initial view controller, the status bar appears as expected- translucent.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971690/fake-status-bar-color-when-navigation-bar-is-hidden) is similar, but none of the solutions worked, it is over a year old, and when I contacted the poster, he said that he thought he put a view underneath where the status bar would be. I'm not sure that I can manage the the view in such a way that it works seamlessly with the scroll aspect of the page view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. A friend of mine made a suggestion which led me to start thinking about the frame of the `UIPageViewController`. This led me to grab the height of the status bar and then adjust the frame down by that much.

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
let pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

// More pageViewController setup

let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height

let x = pageViewController.view.bounds.origin.x
let y = pageViewController.view.bounds.origin.y - statusBarHeight
let width = pageViewController.view.bounds.width
let height = pageViewController.view.bounds.height + statusBarHeight
    let frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

pageViewController.view.frame = frame
```

I still do not understand why this needs to be manually adjusted. (Hopefully someone else will come along with a solution/explanation.) But I hope this bit of code helps someone.