# Why statusbar turns to black when UIView is embedded in NavigationalViewController in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, statusbar, xcode5, uistatusbar

In iOS 7, statusbar should be transparent by default. I am making an app which is using tabs. One tab is showing a simple UIView. I want white statusbar so i just put my view background white and it worked fine. Second tab' view is embedded in Navigational Controller. I set second view's background as white as well. But my statusbar becomes black. And i can't see anything except battery sign. Looks like following images:

Simple view statusbar:
[image]

View Embedded in Navigational Controller statusbar:
[image]

I want white statusbar in my whole app. Any idea why is it happening and how can i fix that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread should help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

In the app delegate try:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Are any of your VC's modal, as above seems ineffective on modal VC's.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made whole app using Xcode 5 ??

I m getting same problem if i am running app from Xcode 4 to Device with ios 7.
If I m making app from Xcode 5 and running in device with iOS 7. It is not giving any such problem

Comment: Its made with Xcode 5 and i am installing it on iPhone with iOS 7. Problem is with only those views which are embedded in navigation controller

Comment: I Reinstalled latest version of Xcode and now i can't even see battery first time i open view embedded in navigation controller. But when i go to a view which is not embedded in navigation controller and then come back then i see normal statusbar with black background.