# Change status bar text colour from white iOS 7 / Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm developing an application for a school that I work at. Currently I am having issues with changing the status bar text from it's default state of black to white so we can actually read it!

I have tried everything i've found here and on the dev forums, including calling `View controller-based status bar appearance = "NO"` and also `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

[image]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I just fixed this issue in one of my apps. Implement this in your UIViewController:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Or choose another `UIStatusBarStyle` value that you need.

Comment: Only answer that worked. None of the others seemed to affect the status bar.

Comment: An outstanding fix. What's more, if you're using navigation controllers within your app via Storyboards that don't necessarily need specific coding to handle what they do, you can use this in a single UINavigationController class that's assigned to each navigation view within the Storyboard.

Comment: this method is not called in my project.

Answer (score 15):

You can use this in your AppDelegate:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

Comment: Only if you also set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO in the Info.plist. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18184831/650558

Comment: It's deprecated in iOS9.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem: 
[How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7?rq=1).

Comment: It's better to just mark the question as a duplicate rather than add an answer saying that it is a duplicate.

Comment: I asked this question because everything in that thread hadn't worked.

Comment: Why the downvotes? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20824667/1533054) worked fine for me (On iOS 7).