# StatusBar text color not change in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I know there are so many question/answer related to my question but no one can help me. As my title said that in my application *(iPad base)* I want to change text color of statusBar in `iOS 7` then how can i do it ??

I also tried on.

[How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

[Change status bar text colour from white iOS 7 / Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977160/change-status-bar-text-colour-from-white-ios-7-xcode-5)

[Status Bar Text Color iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065098/status-bar-text-color-ios-7)

etc..

I just want to set statusBar text color **WHITE** in `iOS 7` ? how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 19):

It's pretty easy

- Go to .plist and set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to
  `NO`.  By default it's not there, you have to add.

[image]

- Go to appDeletegate and under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method paste the below

> Objective-C

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

> Swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

Then see the magic.

Comment: I am not sure why it's not working for you. I have used this in my projects and it's work fine.

Comment: I know, it is easy and your code should be working but its not work for me .. i also dnt know what is problem :( and thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: For me this does not work either. This will remove the status bar entirly

Answer (score 0):

In your project, I recommend going to the General tab and for Status Bar Style select 'Light' in the dropdown.

I also added the 'View controller-based status bar appearance' key to NO in my plist.

Hope this helps.