# ViewControllerBased, Light content Status bar with Transparent Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

In my application i want to add light content status bar with translucent,transparent navigation bar. But when i make my navigation bar transparent it adjust itself with Black status bar content color. Navigation controller is compulsory in my case because table header needs to be stuck to it with plain mode. Any help from you will be appreciated.

[image]
I have used this code for making my navigation bar transparent.

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = true
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

I tried to make status bar appearance light by setting the bar style of navigation controller like

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = .Black/.Default
```

But, still i am facing the same

Comment: [HERE, i got what i was looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29348965/6064629) Finally, this code helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want set **for full application**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

        return true
    }
```

if you want to update only **for view controller**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

}
```

**For iOS 9**

set for **full application**

Just open info.plist and set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `false`

Now update in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

---

only **for view controller**

set View controller-based status bar appearance to **YES**

override below in your view controller

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle 
{ return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent }
```

Comment: @Himanshu please update update your plist as i have suggestion, it must work.

Comment: I want UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance different for different controller that's my requirement.

Comment: override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle 
{ return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent }  This method only works in case there is no navigation attach to your view controller and in my case i need navigation.