# Setting Light Status Bar Objective-C iOS 10

Tags: ios

I am trying to set the status bar to while (light). I have tried everything but still cannot figure out what is going wrong.

[image]

In Info.plist I have the following:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance NO


- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: Do you have UINavigationController in your app?

Comment: Yes I do have UINav controller

Comment: Find your answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29348965/1271424
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called