# Is there an easier way to set the PreferredStatusBarStyle of my app?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm super unhappy with the way I've had to set the EFFING `UIStatusBarStyle` of my app for iOS 7. Essentially I've got a custom presenter that sets up the SlidingPanels navigation (hamburger menu). Inside the custom presenter I define a `RootController`, and this is where I'm confused/ticked off/annoyed... pick one.  <sup>`</rant>`</sup>

Normally I would like to just do something like this and be done with it.

```
RootController = new UIViewController();

// this line won't work because PreferredStatusBarStyle is a Method Group and not a property WTF
RootController.PreferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
```

But there seems to be no way to cleanly set properties in iOS. Therefore I'm stuck with this ugliness.

```
RootController = new CustomUiViewController();

//.....

public class CustomUiViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle()
    {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
    }
}
```

Then in the `ViewDidLoad()` of every view, I have to call `SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`, and this is absurd to me.

**Is there a cleaner/easier way to set this?**

One of the side affects of the above approach is when the app is first loading, the StatusBar is still "dark" and therefore you can't see the clock until after `ViewDidLoad()`.

Comment: If you need the same statusbar style for the whole application check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108513/uistatusbarstyle-preferredstatusbarstyle-does-not-work-on-ios-7).

Comment: @x2_ That's the question I used to get my above code working. What might I be missing?

Comment: Just add to your app's info.plist a couple keys:
`<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>`  
`<false/>`  
`<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>`  
`<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>`

Comment: Ah, that did it. I still had to set the UINavigationBar.Appearance, but at least it's clean now.

Comment: @x2_ post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add to your app's info.plist a couple keys:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```