# Text Color in Navigation Bar Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

i want to have white text in navigation bar but i still have it black whenever i have code for white font.

```
    let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)]
```

I tried

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

but didnt worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you are overwriting the changes each time you set `titleTextAttributes`. Try to set all attributes at the same time:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [        
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot man! u helped me. I Still have one problem with status bar i choosed in app settings Light Content and used code UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true) and its still black.

Comment: At what point in your code (object, method) are you calling this method?

Comment: i have this code in appdelegate.i just want to have my statusbar white but i still have black.

Comment: It might be something to do with the fact that navigation bar controls the status bar style. You might find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108513/uistatusbarstyle-preferredstatusbarstyle-does-not-work-on-ios-7