# UISearchController changing status bar color on invocation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistatusbar, uisearchcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have the following code in my app, specifically in `viewDidLoad:` that sets up my `UISearchController`.

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[];
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleProminent;

[_tableView setTableHeaderView:_searchController.searchBar];
```

Whenever the search bar (which is added to the `tableView`) is invoked, the `UIStatusBar` color changes from `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` to dark (white to black). Now, I figured out if I set,

```
self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
```

to the following:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

the issue is solved and the `UIStatusBar` color is preserved. However, another issue arises. When `self.definesPresentationContext` is set to `YES`
, upon invocation the search bar shifts down for some reason, coincidently (or rightfully so) right under where the bottom of the `UIRefreshControl` displays on the `tableView`.

Comment: Did you  ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: It does not work if i set hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation to YES, bar is changing to black (from white) no matter I do.

Comment: follow this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194368/9079248](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194368/9079248)
it works like a charm

Comment: here is the solution [UISearchController changing status bar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194368/9079248)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting `View-controller based status bar appearance` to `No` is not a solution if you want the view controllers to define how the status bar looks.

My solution consisted of two things:

1. Make sure the presenting view controller has `definesPresentationContext` set to `YES`
2. Make sure both the view controller that is pushed and the pushing view controller are laid out beneath the navigation bar (set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `YES`)

Comment: Interesting fix. Curious, did you have an issue with the search bar shifting down when invoked if extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars was set to NO but definesPresentationContext set to YES?

Comment: Yep. Exactly the same you described.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 10 (maybe earlier?), if you have "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to YES in your Info.plist, simply set the preferredStatusBarStyle in the UIViewController that the UISearchController is included in.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

(you don't need to subclass or create a category/extension of UISearchController to override preferredStatusBarStyle... it uses the preferredStatusBarStyle that you set in your UIViewController)

Comment: This is the right answer, putting it in the `UISearchController` subclass doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I needed full control over my status bar colour. I use the extensions [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37748473/106703) to ensure that the visible view controller is setting the preferred status bar colour.

For me it was therefore necessary to override UISearchController and override `preferredStatusBarStyle` and return the style I wanted.

Comment: This worked fine until iOS 10, did you find any better solution for 10?

Comment: I found the solution: since iOS 10, `UISearchController` asks the presenting view controller (usually your table view controller) for status bar style. You should implement `-preferredStatusBarStyle` there.

Answer (score 1):

If you ViewController is inside a TabBarController then -

**Instead of**
 `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`

**Use** `self.tabBarController.definesPresentationContext = YES;`

This worked for me in above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar that is displayed when the search controller is presented (is active) belongs to the search controller. To set the preferred status bar style you must add a category to UISearchController and then override the preferredStatusBarStyle method.

Below is an example of the implementation file of the category:

```
@implementation UISearchController (Customization)

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -2):

Or we can write an extension on Swift (version 2, but you can translate it to 3 easily):

```
extension UISearchController {

   override public func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle{
      if Theme.lightTheme() {
          return UIStatusBarStyle.Default
      }
      else {
          return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
      }
   }
}
```

Where `Theme` is a class that regulate app colour theme.