# Status bar changes color when searching

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm using a `UISearchController` that, when clicked, makes the navigation bar rise and turn the status bar white. I want the status bar to remain green.

My `UISearchController` implementation:

```
self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Pesquisa por linha ou cod..."
        controller.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xFFFFFF)
        controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x2F7C30)
        controller.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
        controller.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        controller.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x2F7C30).CGColor
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x2F7C30)

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
```

**Before clicking on the search bar**
[image: Before clicking on the search bar]

**After clicking on the search bar**
[image: After clicking on the search bar]

Comment: How are you setting the color of the status bar initially?

Comment: I'm setting the navigation bar background color on my NavigationController.

Answer (score 6):

Playing off of Daniel Storm's response. Adding the subview to the UISearchController's view solved the issue for me.

```
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.width,
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height))
statusBarView.backgroundColor = Colors.Primary.Regular
searchController.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a `UIView` behind your status bar with the background color you need.

```
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame)
statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() // Replace with color you desire
view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Comment: Didn't worked. The view appeared under the navigation bar and in front of the searchbar. And when clicking the searchbar, the view disapeers 

Comment: @MarcioGranzotto what if you called `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(statusBarView)` when the search bar becomes active?

Answer (score 1):

By setting

> scrollEdgeAppearance

> buttonAppearance

> backButtonAppearance

works for me fine here is the code snippet

```
func setNavigationBarAppreance(){

            let navBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    
            let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
   
            navigationBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .primary // replace your desired color
            navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.navigationBarTintColor]
            navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
            navigationBarAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()

            navBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            navBar.compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            navBar.standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            navBar.isTranslucent = false
            navBar.tintColor = .navigationBarTintColor
            navBar.barTintColor = .navBarColor
}
```

Simply use this function in the desired Viewcontrollers or you can put it in the AppDelegate file for global appearance settings

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to set backgroundImage for navigationImage

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(from: UIColor(hexString: kMainColorHex, alpha: 1)), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

Answer (score -1):

For objective C version you can use the following codes:

```
UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height)];
statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor searchBarBackgroundColor];
```

[resultSearchController.view addSubview:statusBarView];

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```