# How to set light-content style to status bar in a phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, ios7

I'm new to phonegap and i try to set the status bar to the new light-content ios7 style.

Is there a possibility to do that yet?

My status bar looks like that...
[image]

... but I want to have this:
[image]

Thanks so much for any help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks for your answers. I've done everthing you wrote before, but it only takes effect on launchscreen, not in the app.

Finally I found the answer on StackOverflow, how to change the status bar style. In PhoneGap you can't do this at the moment I think.

Here is what I did to make it working: 
[How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Comment: Glad you got it all working. Can you tell me which version of cordova/phonegap are you using?

Answer (score 36):

Open your `info.plist` (resources folder):

- set: "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO
- set: "Status bar style" to "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent".

like this:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>

<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

Comment: Worked just fine for me with Cordova 3.3.0! Thanks!

Comment: Works for cordova 3.5.0

Comment: Path for `.plist` file is <yourApp>/platforms/ios/<yourApp>/yourApp-Info.plist

Answer (score 6):

Open the plist of the project as source code and add the following attributes

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Also to set a custom color of status bar you can place the following code in AppDelegate.m
- didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.8f blue:0.8f alpha:1]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Not having screen shots right now, how bad :P.