# White status bar disappears when Navigation bar is visible with Tint Color in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have 2 `UIViewControllers`. In the first `UIViewController`, say `ViewController1` , I am keeping the `UINavigationBar` hidden. As my app's theme is black , so I need white `UIStatusBar` in `iOS 7` so that it doesn't become invisible in black `UINavigationBar`. For getting white `UIStatusBar` I am using this method in `iOS 7`.

1. set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `plist`
2. in `viewDidLoad` do a `[self
   setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`
3. add the following method:

   ```
   -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
     return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
   }
   ```

It works fine when I am in ViewController1 . But when I move to ViewController2 then if I set

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO
```

in my `viewDidLoad` method. Then the above code for white `UIStatusBar` doesn't work. `UIStatusBar` becomes black and I can't see it because I am using the following codes to customize my `UINavigationBar`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

If I keep `UINavigationBar` hidden like ViewController1 then white `UIStatusBar` is visible again. But when `UINavigationBar` is visible then status bar becomes black again. That's the problem.

Can anyone help me in this context , how can I get white status bar like my ViewController1 ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18184831/2800736) may be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried adding this to both view controllers

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably just missing the attribute needed on the plist: View controller-based status bar appearance to NO.

**EDIT**: Check @caglar comment on previous answer for a more comprehensive answer to what's needed in general.