# Changing status bar style ios 7?

Tags: ios, statusbar

I am trying to change the status bar style of one of my viewcontrollers. I have put this

1. set the view based status bar to YES in the plist

2.

```
 -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

1. Added this also

> [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]

It works i.e I can see the font color white but just after some time it changes back to its previous type..

Comment: If you are using storyboards, you should check what values you have set in storyboard for each view controller in status bar.

Also, where are you calling that function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as they mention having tried the technique given in the answer of "How to change status bar text color in iOS 7"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are experiencing status bar changing color itself during runtime

try setting set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to **NO** in the plist.

And inside your viewController.. set the appearance call inside

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

write following code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)Animated{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I could get working for iOS7

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [code](https://github.com/Rogaven/UIViewController-ODStatusBar), a little trick – but useful sometimes.