# Cannot change style of status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar implemented in my iOS App and I set the tint-color to white but when running the app, the status bar does not follow the tint-color and is just transparent (see image). I'm aiming for the status bar to have the translucent style to it.

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing status bar style ios 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447137/changing-status-bar-style-ios-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the the status bar color in all the Viewcontrollers, add this to your info.plist

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

then clean and run the build.

For setting status bar color specific to ViewControllers add the following in the info.plist

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

And in the viewDidLoad method of ViewController call this method :

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

And the add the following method in ViewController :

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

Cheers :]

Comment: It just set the text of the status bar to white. It's still transparent

Comment: refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7

Comment: There are multiple answers, just go through. And let me know if it was of any help. :)

Comment: Found the culprit, I forgot that I have navigationBar.layer.maskToBounds set to true. now it works. Thanks anyways guys!

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried this?

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];//add it in view didload

- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle { 
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
   }
```

Check the Links [add the view in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833724/adding-view-on-statusbar-in-iphone)
check next
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241412/add-uiview-banner-above-status-bar-ios-7)