# How to change status bar background color

Tags: ios, statusbar

Is there way to change the background color of status bar right now it show white with black icons of battery i want the color black here is the code i am using in viewDidLoad

```
     if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: which iOS version u are using right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to **NO**. Call
2. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
           setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

For more details...check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

**EDIT:** try adding this

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 7 the status Bar is transparent. Make sure the background view is Dark if you are setting `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`

For more info You can check the [Apple UITransition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to **YES** in the plist

2) in `viewDidLoad` do a `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]`;

3) add the following method:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{ 
     return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

also check  [developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/)