# IOS 7 status bar is not displayed?

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar

I want to design my navigation bar in IOS7 and i use this code.

```
  UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But my status bar is not displayed(Please see the picture). I use this code in 2 project but other project is ok. I dont know what i am doing wrong Please help me.

This result I dont want

[image]

This status bar is correct.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Info.plist set 
'View controller-based status bar appearance' as NO

In AppDelegate add

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

This solution works for iOS 7