# Cannot set status bar to light content (iOS7)

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar

Firstly, I have tried every answer on this thread: **[How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)** but I am unable to get the status bar to appear with white text.

On app start-up, the text does appear white before it loads into my root view controller. I think the issue is that my root view controller is set to not show the status bar (what I intend) but every other view needs to show it.

When I go to my second view I see the status bar text flash from white to black where it stays.

I have tried setting the status bar to light in the AppDelegate.

I have tried calling `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]` in the rootViewController and in other viewcontrollers. (with `-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` set to return light)

I have set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the plist.

I have no clue why this isn't working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `self.navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;`

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks.