# ios 7 status bar not inheriting nav bar color

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, navbar, ios7-statusbar

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the status bar in ios 7 to use the color of my nav bar. I am using `UINavigationController` in conjunction with the `SWRevealController` library for the sliding menu nav.

This is how a page looks right now:

[image]

I want the status bar to inherit the gray color of the nav bar. How can I do this?

Comment: Checkout this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Comment: Yes it is set to ios7

Comment: try to set color of navigationBar navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

Comment: Quick question. Are you compiling it on XCode5?

Comment: Yup, definitely compiling in xcode 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your project's Info.plist and set 'View controller-based status bar appearance' as NO

In AppDelegate you have to add

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

to AppDelegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method.

Hopefully it will works for you.

Comment: Tried this, I still see the status bar showing up as black

Comment: also visit this link may it will resolve your problem http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/

Comment: This ended up fixing the problem...was doing something wrong elsewhere. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7 navigation bar image height is 64 pixels. You need to create two images, one for navigation bar for iOS 7 with height of 64 pixels and another for iOS 6 or less with height of 44 pixels

Then use this code

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)?YES:NO) {
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your 64 image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 } 
else 
{
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your 44 image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom view and set the color of navigation bar to that view, place this view on the place of status bar, and change the color of your status bar to transparent. 
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)?YES:NO) {
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 } 
else 
{
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previousImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the navigation bar's delegate to be the current view controller and attach the navigation bar to the top.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    navigationBar.delegate = self
}

func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return .TopAttached
}
```