# iphone : How to change the text color ( not the background ) of the status bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, statusbar

How do I change the text color of the status bar? I know how to change the background color but not sure how to change the text color?

I need output like this:

[image]

I am not sure if it is at all possible under Apple HIG but just want to check if we could at all achieve this.

I have see this is done in the System App "Newsstand" . If you see the color is now exactly black or white. It is actually a light gray .

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Comment: @JMarsh  I want to change the text color , when you make it LightCOntent it becomes white . Can you see in my case its not white .

Comment: I'm looking at the image above, it is white, I don't know what you're looking at, and please stop going through my question history and down-voting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't think you can change the text color of Status bar. @JMarsh its not duplicate que. The link you provided is for status bar style not for text.

Comment: From the question in possible duplicate: "How can I change the status bar text color to white like it is on the home screen?" Most of the answers show you can only do white or black.

Comment: @JMarsh But that does not conclude that we can only have black and white as the text color on status bar . I already went through those questions before asking this .

Comment: It is very clear that you can only set the status bar colors to those defined types. You should have been able to conclude that in the first 2 or 3 results returned by Google, which I believe is the general consensus given the current rating of the question.

Comment: I gave a very valid comment for a question that is very easy to find the answer to, though I did not post an answer. Look at the answers here, I am not wrong. Chill out.

Comment: @JMarsh,your comment is valid. Apple is very stringent about look and feel of its product and Status bar style is no exception to that.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to specify the look of the `UIStatusBarStyle`. For a single `UIViewController` use this method:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
   return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

For the whole app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
   setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different styles defined here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIStatusBarStyle

To invoke:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:statusBarStyle animated:NO];
```