# set Status Bar Color as Black in IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

In my app I am set the image of navigationBar.

But I want to status bar as defaultBlack as ios6.

My code is as follow:

```
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    int ver_int = [ver intValue];
    NSString* toReturn=@"";
       toReturn = @"logo_bar.png";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:toReturn] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Help me to solve this.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1):

In view did load check if OS version is 7 or greater.
Then add uiview with background colour as black and with height  at the top of the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image size is 320x64 try an image with size 320x44.I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

do it in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self.navigationController.navigationBar
        setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_bar.png"]
        forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  //...
}
```

or try this to set it to all navbars in you AppDelegate#didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_bar.png"]forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

make sure you are follows the rules for [Creating Resizable Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ResizableImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH30-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

first, change **View controller-based status bar appearance** in your info.plist to YES.
Then use

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
     return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```