# Color text of status bar in XCode 6-b3 (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode6

I've try to modify status bar color text but no one answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7?rq=1) doesn't work.
Any especially for XCode 6?

I've tried insert:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

to `UIViewController`

also

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

to `AppDelegate.swift`
And I've tried change it in `info.plist`
But it doesn't affect it. How change status bar color text to white?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your Info.plist you need to define **View controller-based status bar appearance** to any value.

[image]

If you define it **YES** then you should override `preferredStatusBarStyle` function in each view controller.

If you define it **NO** then you can set style in `AppDelegate` using

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent`

Comment: I got it! I've just don't have "View controller-based status bar appearance" in info.plist. I added it manually and define. Thanks.

Comment: I'd try this in many ways however i can't manage to make it change the color of the UIStatusBar :(

Comment: @JorgeVicenteMendoza, does it always transparent?

Comment: Always Dark! i did try adding the values in the info.plist, trying to override the function in the view controller calling the self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() (that use to work in iOS7) but haven't been hable to make it light

Comment: Do you have UINavigationController or UITabBarController that presents your view controller were you try the override?

Comment: Xcode 6, with Swift:  1. Info.plist, add this property: View controller-based status bar = NO  2. In AppDelegate.swift, inside applicationDidFinishLaunching, add this line: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

Comment: Remember if you're in a UINavigationController you need a custom subclass where you'll override preferredStatusBarStyle.

Answer (score 3):

Just set **" View controller-based status bar appearance == NO "** in to your plist and put a single line in your **appdelegate  class in didfinshLaunching** method.

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

Just set `View controller-based status bar appearance == NO` in to your `*.plist` and put below code in your appdelegate class in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method before `return`.

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

You can change `backgroundColor` and `statusBarStyle` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your info.plist file to `Yes`.

Furthermore, if you are in a UINavigationController, you cannot simply set the style in ViewControllers in it. Subclass the UINavigationController and add this to it:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

    if let vc = self.viewControllers?.last as? UIViewController {
        return vc.preferredStatusBarStyle()
    }

    return super.preferredStatusBarStyle()
}
```

Now you can set the bar style in the UIViewController subclass and the UINavigationController will listen to it :).

Answer (score 0):

Keenle is right on, from iOS7 onward, you have to opt out of viewController-based status bar styles before you can set it app-wide.

doc:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarStyle:animated:

> "To opt out of the view controller-based status bar appearance behavior, you must add the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key with a value of NO to your app’s Info.plist file, but doing so is not recommended."

Comment: This shouldbe a comment, not an answer!