# How to Change the status bar color using ios with swift on internet reachability?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

i want to change the color of my device status bar if the internet is connected than the status bar color should turn Black and if the internet is not connected the color or status bar should turn Red so that it indicates wether internet is working or not during working with the application using SWIFT...help me out

Comment: System wide or just in your app, because as of iOS 7 the status bar is draw over you app, meaning you can easily place a view behind it and give that view ta background color to meet you requirements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color text of status bar in XCode 6-b3 (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746552/color-text-of-status-bar-in-xcode-6-b3-swift)

Comment: Might help anyone still looking for this. [Easy implementation of a colored view behind the status bar.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092646/changing-statusbar-background-color-in-swift)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your `Info.plist` you need to set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to a boolean value.

If you set it to `YES` then you should override `preferredStatusBarStyle` function in each view controller.

If you set it to `NO` then you can set the style in `AppDelegate` using:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

Comment: This only allows you the change the color of the status bar from light to dark.

Comment: you can change it to black or white only

Comment: You can't make it orange or pink , unless you dip your iphone in orange or pink color paint respecvly :D

Comment: But you can put view behind it and give that view any color you want.

Comment: this would rather just change the status from light to dark, i think you didn't get my point

Comment: Yes you can customize it.. putting a view behind it and can put any color u like.. But iOS dont have such native feature

Comment: If you set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO, then you can add another entry to the plist: "Status bar style" with a value of UIStatusBarStyleLightContent instead of putting the code in the app delegate.

Answer (score 30):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden =  true

    //Status bar style and visibility
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
    
    //Change status bar color
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView
    if statusBar.respondsToSelector("setBackgroundColor:") {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted.  I did change it slightly though: `if let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView {// my stuff }`

Comment: This is what I was looking for!! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure where to put this?

Comment: @Mick If you want to apply the style to all UIViewControllers you can put it in AppDelegate `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)`.
If not, this code is supposed to be in the viewWillAppear of your desired UIViewController.

Answer (score 6):

Tested in Swift & iOS9

If you use **Navigation Controllers**, put this in your viewcontroller class:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    ...
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Black
}
```

Otherwise, override the `preferredStatusBarStyle()` in your UIViewController:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

You could find more information [here](http://www.splinter.com.au/2015/12/30/status-bar-colours/)

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 2.3**

Try with these methods

```
// Get network status
class func hasConnectivity() -> Bool {
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus: Int = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value
    return networkStatus != 0
}

// change status bar color
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

`tintColor` attribute change the background color of the navigation bar

`barTintColor` attribute affect to the color of the

But if you want to change the status bar color at the **runtime**, I think the *better way is adding a view behind your status bar*.

Comment: where is the uicolorFromHex func?

Comment: It's my own method to convert *Hex* to `UIColor`. But doesn't matter, you can replace `uicolorFromHex:` by the `UIColor` you want ;)

Comment: I know it is your method but you should write here, I think Stackoverflow have be clear and correct answers.

Comment: May be you're right, I updated the method with UIColor.

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 3**

This should work for Xcode 8 and Swift 3

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @rckoenes commented as of iOS 7 the status bar is draw over your app. So you can put a view behind the status bar area (20px from top - height of status bar) and can control it's background colour as per internet connection status changes, there is no other option you to change status bar colour.

Comment: i have seen an application working with status bar on internet connectivity , without the view behind status bar, it work with the color or status bar in obj c but for swift i have to search that out

Comment: @FattiKhan If you have any app for reference you can mention it and if you can do it with obj c then definitely you can do with swift. If you have any reference code then share that also.

Comment: in some cases you will also have to set the opacity to 0.9 to get the color to match with the nav bar

Answer (score 2):

// Within your AppDelegate.swift in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

```
//Optionally, if you need a specific color, how you do it with RGB:
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

                                or
```

> In your Info.plist you need to set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to a boolean value.

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Comment: Are there any additional settings that needs to be made? This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Andrej  Open your info.plist and insert a new key named "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO then  add this code in UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent // AppDelegate.swift in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Setting the custom color (eg. `UIColor.greenColor()` ) doesn't work. However I can confirm that setting to predefined style `.LightContent` works ok.

Comment: Aha, sorry. Only now I've noticed that the custom color can be set only to `UINavigationBar`, but not to the status bar. The question title is about the status bar only.

Answer (score 0):

To have white text in black status bar:
 Switch **View controller-based status bar appearance** to **NO** in **Info.plist**
In AppDelegate.swift add 
`let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black`
in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score -1):

```
UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent, animated: true)
```