# Changing UIStatusBar color to specific color with RGB?

Tags: swift

I want to change UIStatusBar color using with rgb. Is it possible?

I tried(but I failed)

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.UIColor(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. You can switch between `.LightContent` and `.Default`.

Take a look at this one as well : [How to Change the status bar color using ios with swift on internet reachability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124214/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-using-ios-with-swift-on-internet-reachability)

This one applies to the color of the battery, network etc. You can set background color by setting one on the navigation bar or by placing view inside view controller if you don't use navigation bar.