# Customize iOS 7 status bar text Color

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6

I want to know if there is a way to change the iOS 7 status bar text color besides **black** and **white** color?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465486/change-status-bar-text-color-ios-other-than-black-or-white

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Comment: @iDev: No, I have read the link before. But, like most of the question, it only set the text color to be black or white. What I want is to make the text color to be green. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically this is possible. You will need to read about private api's on iOS. Here is o good place to start with UIStatusBar example:

http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/using-private-ios-apis/

Keep in mind that probably you won't be able to submit your app on Appstore if you would use private api.

Answer (score 6):

Put this in your AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

**Swift 4.2:**

```
if UIApplication.shared.responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))),
    let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView,
    statusBar.responds(to: #selector(getter: CATextLayer.foregroundColor)) {
    statusBar.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "foregroundColor")
}
```

**Swift 3.0:**

Just in case Apple decides to change the naming of the class (highly unlikely) we shall add some type-safety.

```
if application.responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))),
   let statusBar = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView,
   statusBar.responds(to: Selector(("foregroundColor"))) {
   statusBar.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "foregroundColor")
}
```

**Swift 2.0:**

```
application.valueForKey("_statusBar")?.setValue(UIColor.redColor(), forKey: "_foregroundColor")
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[[application valueForKey:@"_statusBar"] setValue: [UIColor redColor] forKey: @"_foregroundColor"];
```

It's hard to say if your app will be rejected from the app store. Using KVC to access the `_statusBar` property will not get your app rejected as the `UIApplication` class itself is not hidden.

That being said, neither is the `UIStatusBar` class hidden, ie. it's not in the SDK's **PrivateFrameworks** directory nor marked with  `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` nor does the class name begin with an underscore.

If your app was rejected because of using this please comment below so I can update the answer.

Comment: This will likely break if services such as a call or location or microphone are used. It's good to add the same code in a notification handler for `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrame`.

Comment: @LeoNatan Would it not be better to use KVO on the `_foregroundColor` property and change the colour back to red there? Ofc guarding against the colour being the same to avoid recursion.

Comment: That key may not be KVO compliant. Indeed, most of UIKit isn't.

Comment: Are you sure? It was my understanding that all Foundation Objective-C classes are compliant to KVO automatically. I know you need the `dynamic` keyword for swift. Is there something similar for Obj-C?

Comment: UIKit is not Foundation. ObjC always uses dynamic dispatch, while in Swift you need to explicitly state it. If your class inherits form `NSObject`, its public and internal methods and properties also use dynamic dispatch due to `@objc` compliance.

Comment: UIColor inherits from NSObject though. Why would there be a problem observing it?

Comment: UIColor objects are immutable, what do you want to observe on colors? You want to observe a property that has changing colors, a property of `UIStatusBar`. A crash course on KVO compliance: if you change the value of the underlying instance variable by any other means than using the setter method, a property is no KVO compliant. Since `UIStatusBar` is a private class, there is no way of knowing it is KVO compliant in all cases.

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStatusBar.h

Comment: Suggest reading on KVO compliance: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html

Comment: You're a genius!