# Setting custom color of status bar text

Tags: ios

In iOS8 I want to set the color of the status bar text (carrier, time, battery) to a custom color.

I've set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` and tried this code in both the individual viewcontroller, and the app delegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:color_font];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: Do you put these instruction in your AppDelegate file?

Comment: in the view controller

Comment: Add them in your AppDelegate  file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In iOS8 I want to set the color of the status bar (Carrier, time, battery) to a custom color.

This is not possible right now without using private API ([Customize iOS 7 status bar text Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053844/customize-ios-7-status-bar-text-color)). You can only make the status bar's text white (`UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`) or black (`UIStatusBarStyleDefault`). Check the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStatusBarStyle

You can put a view behind the status bar (per everyone else's answer), but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try like this in your AppDelegate

```
UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 20);
addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]]; //assign here your color 
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding size, it is better to refer to status bar properties.

Comment: I'm not disputing that. I'm commenting on the static size you've given to your `view`'s `frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your app info.plist

1) Set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

Then Add Costom View on status bar in your project AppDelegate

```
UIView *statusBarViewObj = [[UIView alloc] init];
statusBarViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 20);
statusBarViewObj.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]];  
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:statusBarViewObj];
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding size, it is better to refer to status bar properties

Answer (score 0):

Create a view, put it where the status bar will be, and set its background color to which ever color you require. For example:

Objective C:

```
UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width,
                        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height)];
statusBarView.backgroundColor  =  [UIColor greenColor]; // Replace with color you desire
[self.view addSubview:statusBarView];
```

Swift:

```
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.width,
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height))
statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() // Replace with color you desire
self.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```