# Dynamically change status bar text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, statusbar, ios7-statusbar

I know I can change the iPhone's status bar text color, using methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7).

However, my app has different themes, and I need to update the status bar accordingly.

Calling

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

and

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

will obviously not work. However, it needs to be local, as in only for a specific TabBar view.

Comment: In what way will it not work? You can make those calls when the theme changes...

Comment: @Wain Of course I can. Sorry, too late here already. Didn't think straight...

Answer (score 1):

First, select your `Project` and in the `Genernal` tab you will see something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeJV5.png)

Then set `Status Bar Style` to `Light` just like the image.

Second, set `View controller-based status bar appearance equal` to `NO` in Info.plist. If you can't find it, just add a new row and set it like the above step.

And then, run your app you will see the Status bar text colour is white. :)

Comment: sorry for the image link, because my reputation is not enough to post image directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the ones who come here for the title.
You can set a flag and toggle between the status bar text colors like in the code segment given:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {

if (barStyleLight){

    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
else {

    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

}

Also note that, this `preferredStatusBarStyle` method is called whenever we call: `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

Hope it helps.