# How to change the status bar bgcolor for UITableView with hidden nav bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

The UITableView is inside NavigationController, but navigation bar hidden by this line:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

**What I've tried:**

- [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7): tried the 1 & 2nd steps, didn't work. (the 3rd step would make all text in status bar white)
- modify the frame of the 1st cell in:

  ```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:

  // for the 1st cell, move frame up to cover status bar
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      CGRect frame = cell.frame;
  //  frame.origin.y -= 50;
      frame.size.height += 50;
      cell.frame = frame;
  }
  ```

Comment: Set the tableview background color to redcolor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I had to set the background color of the whole UITableView, simple as that.

Comment: what about the status bar? Did they change automatically to white?

Answer (score 0):

Set the tableview background color to the redcolor then status bar will be shown in redcolor