# iOS TableViewController set statusbar color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there any way to set `statusbar` `lightcontent` color to a `UITableViewController`?

Looks like there is no function

```
override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }
```

in `UITableViewController`

Comment: No, there's no way to specify the color of the items in the status bar.

Comment: Unsure if this is what you're after but could this question be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332638/how-to-change-the-status-bar-bgcolor-for-uitableview-with-hidden-nav-bar

Comment: try to set navigation bar appearance tint color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding barStyle to black fixed the problem

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use **Navigation Bar**

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
}
```

If you don't use **Navigation Bar** only change color Background view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
```