# uiactivityviewcontroller set status bar light content

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS 8, when presenting an `UIActivityViewController`, trying to set status bar content light does not work. It shows black text.

I've tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[viewController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES
    completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES]; 
}];
```

View controller-based status bar appearance is set to NO in the plist.

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7) with no luck. It could very well be a bug, as I don't have this issue with `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: @gabbler Not working for me. I chose to hide the status bar for now, but ideally would like to unhide if this ever gets solved

Comment: I don't know what your project setting is, do you have `Status bar is initially hidden` being set in your plist file? I made a really simple project and it worked for me. Do you have a navigation bar? You might want to share more detail or maybe share a sample project if you really want it to be resolved.