# setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate crash my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uistatusbar

I need to change the color of status bar in my app.I'm using the code below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     ....
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

but this cause my app to crash.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error
```

It is sometimes produce memory warning.

What is the best way to handle this ?

Comment: similar to this question
refer this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Comment: I do not want the way to do this,I did it .However,My app crash and I want to solve this problem.

Comment: Dear Matthias Bauch, this question is not related to the unrecognised selector question. Can you please remove the duplicate mark?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
if ([self  respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
 {
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

if your app supports older version than iOS 7,and you ever need to use something such as setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate , you can first check if the selector is supported

Comment: This problem does not related to compatibility issues

Comment: How in the word the unrecognised selected can produce BAD_ACCESS?