# Status bar in ios flashes or changes its color

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

The UIStatusbar tint color is initally white colored , when i add a childview controller subview it is turned to black or when i push a new viewcontroller through the navigation controller it flashes.

Any idea why this happens

Answer (score 0):

The status bar changes colors to adapt to its environment. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7) if you want to overwrite this behavior.