# How can I make the status bar match a UINavigationBar's colour in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar, navigationbar

I'm trying to match the colour of the status bar with the colour of my UINavigationBar in Swift. I've added a UINavigationBar to my view controller, but I'm unable to match the status bar's colour.

Would I have to use a UINavigationBar, or is there another more convenient way?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7 and the comment on UINavigationControl?

Comment: I'm not using a UINavigationController. I manually inserted the bar into my view controller.

Comment: Then the first part of the post I linked tells you how to do that. One of the comments is to address UINavigationController and that's apparently not for you.