# Can not see wifi / time info top of my app

Tags: ios, storyboard

Initial viewController looks like below. Main `view` background color is set to `clear`, no container is above the **wifi / time** symbols. Why am I not able to see those infos, but only a black background?

[image]

[image]

tried status bar setting to change, but without any luck:

[image]

Comment: why -1, I think it is a fairly reasonable question?

Comment: a _dark_ text on a _dark_ background is usually not visible. based on that simple fact, I can tell you, your question is quite silly, I'm not wondering about the downvotes; you need to change your statusbar to light colour and your problem would be solved. much quicker than making a post about it.

Comment: I set background to `clear`, `clear` is not `dark`

Comment: oh, do you think that makes a huge difference...? as I just told you, you need to set your statusbar to light colour, and your problem is solved. it can be done in... let me think... about 3 secs, I guess I have not overestimated the time.

Comment: That setting only change the appearance in Storyboard !

Comment: I changed background color to `white`, that helped, but `Status Bar` color has no effect

Comment: The default background is `black` so when you set a `view`'s background to `clear` it's going to show you the app's background (which is `black`).

Comment: @János, you need to override the `–preferredStatusBarStyle` method in your view controller... changing this value in IB is effectless.

Answer (score 0):

Because default status bar icon tint color is black.

Set status bar style to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

[More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Just add this 2 key to your info.plist

[image]

Comment: You can do this in the Project Settings screen in Xcode.

Comment: Shouldn't you set the "View controller-based status bar..." to `YES` to make it dynamic based on the background?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set into the AppDelegate in "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:"

```
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

If still you don't see it set it not hidden like this:

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```