# Change Navigation Bar text colour

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to change the status bar text (the text at the top of the screen with the time, battery percentage, etc) to white. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

If your view controller is within a navigation controller, in the view controller's `.m` , use this line in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Comment: Your question is about the status bar but your answer is about a navigation bar.