# Status Bar Icons Turn Black when Search Bar is active

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar, searchbar

Okay, so...

I have set the `NavigationBar` `Style` to `Black` so that the Status Bar Icons become White.

(See Pic 1 Below)

[image: Pic 1 - Status Bar Icons White, as they Should be]

The Problem begins with the Search Bar. When it's active and you can type it turns the `NavigationBar` `Style` back to `Default` which makes the Status Bar Icons Black again. Though once you are done with it and it goes back to being inactive, the `NavigationBar` `Style` goes back to `Black`, where it should be all the time.

(See Pic 2 Below)

[image: Pic 2 - Status Bar Icons Black - Not Good]

I haven't found a way yet to make the Status Bar Icons remain White at all times.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have view controller based status bar appearance setup.

If you want the status bar to be white **all** the time, then you can set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` info.plist key to `NO` and then set `UIStatusBarStyle` key to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

If you do want to keep view controller based status bar appearance, then you will need to subclass `UISearchController` and override the status bar style as you are technically presenting a different view controller for search hence the change in status bar style...

```
class SearchController: UISearchController {

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }
}
```

(note that i assume you are using `UISearchController` as your question doesn't mention your approach)