# IOS navigation bar tintColor wont turn white when navigationController is set to false

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I've been having a problem with one of my Xcode projects. I'm trying to hide the navigation bar of an IOS app, but retain a white tint on the time, carrier and battery section/icons. I can only turn the tint white if I have the navigationController set to false in `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false`
When it is set to true, the tint turns white and there is no issue, but the navigation bar is there in color. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signinBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signupBtn: UIButton!


    var varView = Int()



    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        emailTxt.delegate = self

        let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
        let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

        emailTxt.frame = CGRectMake(40, 200, theWidth-80, 30)
        passwordTxt.frame = CGRectMake(40, 240, theWidth-80, 30)

        signinBtn.frame = CGRectMake(theWidth-228, 340, 59, 30)

         signupBtn.frame = CGRectMake(theWidth-228, 390, 59, 30)

        let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        nav?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true








        //maparea


    }



    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //emailTxt.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func signInBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(emailTxt.text!, password: passwordTxt.text!) {
            (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                print("logIn")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoMainVCFromSigninVC", sender: self)

            } else {

                print("error")
            }

        }

    }

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller you can override `preferredStatusBarStyle` like this:

```
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

Comment: In case you want the dark status bar style, return `.Default` instead

Comment: No problem @LarryNavarro! If my answer was right, please mark it as such! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not relate navigation bar. It relate to status bar. Your status bar is `lightContent` so you will see white. You just change it to `Default` and you will see better.

And change status bar with `viewcontroller` is:

1. Set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES in the
   .plist file.
2. In the viewDidLoad do a [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
3. Add the following method:

   ```
   override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
       return .Default
   }
   ```

In your case is navigation so do it:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

answer of @adrianokw would be for one viewcontroller , if you want to do it for whole app add the following to info.plist

Status bar style
**UIStatusBarStyleLightContent**

View controller-based status bar appearance
**NO**

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)