# Change statusbar text color programmatically inside the same view controller

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using UIScrollView on iOS 9 with two pages and for the first page I want the statusbar text to be black and the second page white. So when I slide to the second page I want the statusbar color to turn white and black if I slide to the first page.

I have tried setting the 
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to false in the plist file
and then programmatically calling:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.BlackTranslucent;
SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
```

But without luck, the statusbar text appears white and it stays white even when calling UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.BlackTranslucent;

Any idea how to manually change the statusbar text color within the same view controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a Navigation Controller for your view controllers, try changing the property:

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle
```

"Default" should be black and "LightContent" should be white. I believe the Black options are deprecated.

Otherwise, you could opt for View Controller based Status Bar Style in your Info.plist and use the [preferredStatusBarStyle property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredStatusBarStyle) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7?rq=1).

In your ViewDidLoad method, do `SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();`

Add the following method:

```
 public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle()
 {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent; //Or Default/Black/etc.
 }
```

Note: Using `UIApplication.SharedApplication` to change the status bar style has been deprecated in iOS 9. Use the above methods instead. Hope this helped. Cheers!

Comment: This worked, I had to use UIStatusBarStyle.Default instead of BlackTranslucent for the black color. But animation is not working for some reason. I set the UIStatusBarAnimation PreferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation to UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade but it's not working.

Comment: I've updated the question with the "Default" == black thing you mentioned. :) I'll look into the animation problem and report back if I find anything.

Comment: Great, thanks. Regarding the animation part, I had to wrap it update command into the command animation like this:UIView.Animate(0.3f, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate, () => {});

Answer (score 4):

Go to your application Plist and add this as new row & set it as NO.

View controller-based status bar appearance  NO

Add a bool to determine state of UIStatusBar colour & add a Toggle method

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL black;


-(void)toggleStatuSBar:(id)sender{

    if(black) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
        black = NO;

    }else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
        black = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If use Navigation controller then add:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```