# changing status bar color depending on time

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

Not sure if it is possible, but is there a way to change the status bar color depending on the time? I was fiddling with this code:

```
import UIKit

class testTimeController: UIViewController{

func lightstatusbar() {
var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
 }
}

  func darkstatusbar() {
var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default
}
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: NSDate() as Date)

 switch hour{
    case 1..<6: lightstatusbar()
        break
    case 7..<18: darkstatusbar()
        break
    case 19..<24: lightstatusbar()
        break
    default: darkstatusbar()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious if your solution really works. If not, I added a working solution, which I've tested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers don't work for me, so here is my working solution, regarding to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41222656/5327882):

**Step 1** Add following to your `info.plist`:

`View controller-based status bar appearance` with Boolean value `NO`

[image]

**Step 2** Add this to `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: NSDate() as Date)

  switch hour {
  case 1..<6:
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
  case 7..<18:
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
  case 19..<24:
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
  default:
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
  }

  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but instead just implement and ovveride

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: NSDate() as Date)

     switch hour{
    case 1..<6: .lightContent
        break
    case 7..<18: .darkContent
        break
    case 19..<24: .lightContent
        break
    default: .darkContent
}
```

Dont put the var inside another method that wont do anything.

Comment: Tweaked it a bit, but it worked like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used @SeanLintern88 approach, just added "return"

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: NSDate() as Date)

    switch hour{
    case 1..<6: return.lightContent

    case 7..<18: return.default

    case 19..<24: return.lightContent

    default: return.default
    }
}
```

Comment: this really works for you? What if you just set `let hour = 1`, to test if your status bar is `.lightContent`? Just tested the code and for me it's not working