# Styling UINavigationBar to match the style in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a tap bar that with 3 items. The first item is a `UISplitView` showing a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. The other two items are simple `UIViewControllers` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

The two `UIViewControllers` embedded in a `UINavigationController` have a navigation bar with their title provided by the `UINavigationController` and "default" color.

I added a `UINavigationBar` to the `UINavigationController` in the first item but it has different color, it is white (Messages in the gif):

[image]

So I found out the default color of the `UINavigationBar` embedded in a `UINavigationController` and set it in code

```
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: (247/255), green: (247/255), blue: (247/255), alpha: 1)
```

The navigation bar changes color but the status bar remains white:

[image]

I tried the accepted answer from [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7) but it did not help.

So how do I style the `UINavigationBar` in my view controller so it exactly matches the default one in navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we worked together at Fuerte International a couple of years ago!

The status bar doesn't have a colour, it should just be the colour of your background view. Change the colour of that and you should see the status bar change too?

Comment: yes, Fuerte, the old time when Windows Phone was not dead yet :)