# how to change the color of text in StatusBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to change the text color of status bar content.
i want color like yellow ,green etc.
not system provided style
I has changed the color of status bar but not changing the text color of status bar.

Comment: May this help you - [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7?rq=1)

Comment: i want the color of my choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can switch between dark and light color by overriding [preferredStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle) in a viewController:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

However, you have [two options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarstyle) only, either `.default` or `.lightContent`, for dark text color and light text color, respectively. You cannot use any color that you want. Although I can imagine implementing your own custom status bar, and hiding the system status bar - although you might have difficulties getting to all the system info that the system status bar presents.

Answer (score 3):

you can change using below code .
Place this code in app Delegate 
in method

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackTranslucent

}
```

or

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle =.lightContent
```

You can't set custom  color to it .

Comment: i want the color of my choice

Comment: This approach is deprecated since iOS 9. However, I still use it too, because it's much more flexible than the "correct" `preferredStatusBarStyle` approach...