# colorize or show image statusbar on flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, statusbar

I'm struggling with the column and listview widgets

I tried build a screen but with all the contents on smaller screens it's better if I could add a scrollview.
The documentation suggest using the ListView so everything automatically becames scrollable.

For that matter, things are quite ready already, here comes the struggle:
[status bar problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WctII.png)

the preview to the right I'm using Column and it is overlaped with the clock and battery meter
the preview to the left I'm using ListView, but the status bar is shown with this white color

I tried things here but nothing changed except for the icon colors based on light/dark themes. See: [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios)

any other suggestion? or some guideline for building correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView is made like this in case when there are no AppBar in UI.

To resolve this issue wrap your ListView in `MediaQuery.removePadding` Widget.

Like this

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        child: getListBody(),
      )
```

Remember that the context parameter is required to inherit the padding properties of widget tree.

Comment: Thanks for the help... worked like a charm. Didn't find anything with that approach. I'll look for more of this MediaQuery