# Change status bar text colour when using swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, statusbar

Looking to change the status bar text colour (on a per view basis) using swiftui but cannot seem to do it?

I can change it for the whole app but some screens have a different status bar colour so the text needs to switch from black to white when the background is dark?

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios/17768797#17768797

Comment: Doesn’t work, that sets it up for the whole app, I want per screen adjustment as per my question