# Change status bar text color on fullScreenCover with iOS 15

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios15

I usually use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575788/5653544) to change the status bar text color with SwiftUI. But since iOS 15, the status bar color text is automatically set to black when I present a view with `.fullScreenCover` and I can't change its color. However, I still can change status bar text color on a navigation view.

Is there another way to change the status bar text color on View presented by `.fullScreenCover` on iOS15 ?

XCode Version: 13.0 (13A233)

iOS Version: 15.0

Comment: I think you might be looking for [modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621453-modalpresentationcapturesstatusb?language=objc) - I doubt there's native support for this in SwiftUI yet.