# How to change the status bar text color in swift using @main

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been trying for quite a while now to change the status bar color on a specific view to white when the top of the view's background is black but the color scheme of the view is on light mode. I am using @main for my app's launch point and SwiftUI for my app's code.

Thank you for any help and here's a screenshot to show what I'm talking about:

[image: My frustration, illustrated]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575788/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```js
var body: some View {
  ZStack { ... }
  .preferredColorScheme(.dark OR .light) // white tint on status bar
}
```